# Select options based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select option like this

```
<select name="category" class="category">
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="mid">Mid</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
</select>
<select name="details" class="details">
    <option value="2">john</option>
    <option value="5">smith</option>
    <option value="2">james</option>
    <option value="3">bram</option>
    <option value="10">gary</option>
</select>
```

When I select low, I want in details just show john, james, and bram. For mid, I want details just show smith and for high I want details just show gary. How I can do that with jquery?

The range is 1-4 low, 5-9 is mid, >10 is high.

Comment: How do you map low, mid, high to 1, 5 and 10?

Comment: 1-4 low, 5-9 mid, >10 high

Comment: @ghabriel  then second-select-box need to be multi-select

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: @AlivetoDie not selected, just dropdown options showing what it's related from first select option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to loop through your `option` list and hide/show them accordingly.

Here, I use a `switch` to limit which options to hide/show.

```js
$('.category').on('change',function(){
  switch ($(this).val()){
    case 'low':
      $('.details option').each(function(){
        if(+$(this).val() <= 4) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
     case 'mid':
      $('.details option').each(function(){
        if(+$(this).val() <= 9 && +$(this).val() >= 5) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
     case 'high':
      $('.details option').each(function(){
        if(+$(this).val() == 10) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
  }
});

$('.category').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" class="category">
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="mid">Mid</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
</select>
<select name="details" class="details">
    <option value="2">john</option>
    <option value="5">smith</option>
    <option value="2">james</option>
    <option value="3">bram</option>
    <option value="10">gary</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First to know that I can use if statement like that. Thankyou for new knowledge and it works like a charm

Comment: @ghabriel Glad I could help. I suggest you take look at the [`switch` statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). It will help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Change de value for de details select to the according category.
So change 2 to low, 5 to mid and 10 to high. 
Then you can get the selected category value and put it in below code to select option by value.

```
<select name="category" class="category">
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="mid">Mid</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
</select>
<select name="details" class="details">
    <option value="low">john</option>
    <option value="mid">smith</option>
    <option value="low">james</option>
    <option value="mid">bram</option>
    <option value="high">gary</option>
</select>

$('.category').on('change',function(){    
    var category = $(this).val();   
    $(".details option[value!='"+category+"']").hide();
    $(".details option[value='"+category+"']").show();
    $(".details").val($(".details option:visible:first").val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cpjn5nb/

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this code:

```
$(".category").change(function() {
  var t = $(this).val();
  $(".details option").filter(function(i, x) {
    if (t == "low") {
      $(x).val() >= 1 && $(x).val() <= 4 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    } else if (t == "mid") {
      $(x).val() >= 5 && $(x).val() <= 9 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    }
    else {
      $(x).val() > 10 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    }
  });
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".category").change(function() {
  var t = $(this).val();
  $(".details option").filter(function(i, x) {
    if (t == "low") {
      $(x).val() >= 1 && $(x).val() <= 5 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    } else if (t == "mid") {
      $(x).val() > 5 && $(x).val() <= 9 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    }
    else {
      $(x).val() > 10 ? $(x).show() : $(x).hide()
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" class="category">
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="mid">Mid</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
</select>
<select name="details" class="details">
    <option value="2">john</option>
    <option value="5">smith</option>
    <option value="2">james</option>
    <option value="10">gary</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a Javascript Object that will store the options you want for mid,low,high. After that you simply have to create a Function that will be called each time the user changes your main Selection , and this function will search through your Object to find the appropriate options to display.

**Note :** The below Example is **without the use** of any External Library like jQuery , etc.

```js
var myOptionsObject = {
 "low" : ["john","smith","james"],
 "mid" : ["bram"],
 "high" : ["gary"]
}

function loadSubSelect(myIndex){
 var parentEl = document.getElementById('myParentSelect');
 var childEl = document.getElementById('mySubSelect');
 var mySelectedValue = parentEl.options[myIndex].value;

// Create the New Select with the appropriate options given from "myOptionsObject"
 var mySubSelect = '<select name="details" class="details">';
 myOptionsObject[mySelectedValue].forEach(function(key){
  mySubSelect += '<option value="'+key+'">'+key+'</option>'; 
 });
 mySubSelect += "</select>";

 childEl.innerHTML = mySubSelect;
}

// Execute the below Function to get the first results
loadSubSelect(1);
```

```html
<div id='parentSelect'>
 <select name="category" id='myParentSelect' class="category" onChange="loadSubSelect(this.selectedIndex);">
     <option value="low">Low</option>
     <option value="mid">Mid</option>
     <option value="high">High</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div id='mySubSelect'></div>
```